# If $N\lhd G$ then $n_p(G/N) \leq n_p(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I want to prove the above statement where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $n_p(G) = \vert Syl_p(G)\vert$, i.e. the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

I am quite stuck on this problem. My initial thought was to define a map from the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ to those of $G/N$ and then show that the map is surjective, but this turns into a gargantuan mess with a ton of Lagrange cardinality and divisibility arguments and such, and does not quite get me what I want to show anyway even with a substantial amount of hand-waving.

Any suggestions? I also naturally thought about trying to prove it indirectly by way of contradiction, though I really am not certain how to even begin to go about it that way.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: Use that $n_p = |G: N_G(P)|$ but for the case of $G/N$ and this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291257/sylow-subgroup-of-g-h

Answer (score 5):

Even something stronger is true.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group, $N \unlhd G$, then $n_p(G/N) \mid n_p(G)$.

One proof (it can also be shown in a different way, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940442/prove-that-n-pn-divides-n-pg/940662)) hinges on the following lemma of which the easy proof can be found for example in the book of I.M. Isaacs, *Finite Group Theory*, remarks made on page $23$. Note that if $H \leq G$ and $N \unlhd G$, then $N \subseteq HN \subseteq N_G(HN)$. Also, since $N$ is normal, $N_G(H) \subseteq N_G(HN)$.

**Lemma** Let $G$ be a group, $H \leq G$, $N \unlhd G$, then $$N_{G/N}(HN/N)=N_G(HN)/N.$$
Now, every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$ is of the form $PN/N$, for some $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Hence, $n_p(G/N)=|G/N:N_{G/N}(PN/N)|= \text{(by the lemma) }= |G/N:N_G(PN)/N|=|G:N_G(PN)|$. But, $N_G(P) \subseteq N_G(PN)$, hence $n_p(G/N)=|G:N_G(PN)| \mid |G:N_G(PN)| \cdot |N_G(PN): N_G(P)|= |G:N_G(P)|=n_p(G)$ and we are done.

Answer (score 4):

The key idea is the correspondence isomorphism theorem: there is a bijection between subgroups of $G/N$ and subgroups of $G$ containing $N$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N$. If $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $G$, then $f(P)$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$ ($[G:PN]=[H:f(P)]$, and $f(P)$ is a $p$-group). If $Q$ is a Sylow subgroup of $H$, there is a subgroup $N\le K\le G$ such that $f(K)=Q$.  If $L$ is a Sylow subgroup of $K$, then also $f(L)=Q$ (by the first part, and since $f(L)\le f(K)=Q$).

That means that every Sylow subgroup of $H$ has a Sylow preimage in $G$, so $n_p(H)\le n_p(G)$.