# How to prove that $n_p (G) = n_p ({\rm Inn}(G))$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Prove $n_p (G) = n_p ({\rm Inn} (G))$ when $G$ is a finite group and $n_p$ is the number of sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now, but it seems that this question is harder than it sounds.

My idea is to find a bijection between ${\rm Inn}$ (inner automorphism group) and $G/Z$

However this needs some work and I'm not even sure if it can help.

(English isn't my first language and this is my first time taking the group theory. So please pardon my mistakes. I am not sure if the notations I used here are widely standard or not)

Comment: ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$, so you should try and prove the result for $G/Z(G)$. (So, yes, it can help.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes that's indeed my thought. And I was able to prove the isommrphism between $G/Z$ and the inner automorphism group. Now I don't know how to prove the result :/

Comment: Use the fact that $n_p(G) = |G:N_G(P)|$ for $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, and $Z \le N_G(P)$.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [If $N\lhd G$ then $n_p(G/N) \leq n_p(G)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498898/if-n-lhd-g-then-n-pg-n-leq-n-pg), even, if $N \unlhd G$ then $n_p(G/N)$ *divides* $n_p(G)$. And $n_p(G/N)=n_p(G)$ if and only $N \subseteq N_G(P)$ ($P \in Syl_p(G)$). Now always $Z(G) \subseteq N_G(P)$, as prof. Holt also pointed out.